# How to retrieve data from two tables using "joins"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner in Ruby-on-Rails and I started to investigate ActiveRecords. And I run into one problem.

I have two tables: `todo_lists` and `users`. The first one has following records: `title`, `description`, `user_id`, `deadline`. And the second one has only one record: `name`. I want to get a table that contains following records: `title`, `description`, `name`, `deadline`, i.e. combine two tables and put `user` instead of `user_id`. I try to solve this problem using `joins`:

```
TodoList.joins(:user).select("todo_lists.title, todo_lists.description, users.name, todo_lists.deadline")
```

But I get the new `ActiveRecord::Relation` without `users.name`:

`[#<TodoList id: nil, title: "This is title", description: "This is description", deadline: "2020-03-13 18:59:58">]`

This is my `todo_list.rb` and `user.rb` files:

```
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todo_lists
end
```

`schema.rb` file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_13_183504) do

  create_table "todo_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "is_disabled"
    t.datetime "deadline"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "todo_lists", "users"
end
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is to access the user name from each object in the `TodoList::ActiveRecord_Relation`, you can use AS and give the proper name, which allows you to use it as a method from a single record on the ActiveRecord_Relation holding the user name:

```
TodoList.joins(:user).select("..., users.name AS user_name").first.user_name
```

Otherwise you can use `as_json`, which returns an array containing the data of every record as a hash, where each key is the column and the value, the corresponding values in the select statement:

```
TodoList.joins(:user).select("todo_lists.description, users.name").as_json
# [{"id"=>nil, "description"=>"1st", "name"=>"user1", ...},
#  {"id"=>nil, "description"=>"2nd", "name"=>"user2", ...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Palma's is a good answer to the question as asked. It asked specifically how to solve this problem using `joins`.

That said, I think the traditional ActiveRecord approach to this problem is to use your models and associations.

You can add a `user_name` method to the TodoList model like this:

```rb
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def user_name
    user.name
  end
end
```

Now, any TodoList instance will return the name of its associated User regardless of how it was queried.

To avoid an n + 1 query scenario, you can use `preload(:user)` when querying TodoLists. For example, this code will make 2 queries to get the last 10 TodoLists and their associated Users.

```rb
TodoList.preload(:user).last(10)
```